# What "metrics" are logged in a Tensorflow2.0 Keras Callback?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

According to the Tensorflow2.0 Keras ModelCheckpoint [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), the callbacks monitor the metric specified by the `monitor` argument, whose default value is `"val_loss"`.

What "metrics" are available, and where are they documented? Metrics such as `"mse"`, `"val_acc"`  used in scattered examples, but I couldn't find any documentations that give a complete list of what's logged by default.

I went through the official guides on [writing CallBacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback) but it does not explain it either.

Answer (score 0):

Available both in TensorFlow 1.14 and in higher versions(including TensorFlow 2.0), many more metrics are available than the plain 'accuracy'.

Nonetheless, you need to explicitly tell your 'model' to use them.

For example, for a classification problem, you might be interested in '`tensorflow.keras.metrics.Recall`', '`tensorflow.keras.metrics.Precision`', 
'`tensorflow.keras.metrics.TruePositives`'.

You can find many more metrics here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics.

An example of how to use them is here:

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Recall, Precision, TrueNegatives, TruePositives
model.compile(optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.002),
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=[Recall(),Precision(),TrueNegatives(),TruePositives()])
```

This being said, if you specify them like in the above example, you have access to them in your 'logs' dictionary.